# How to stop childview from getting spilled over inside scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, childviews

I have a scrollview which has a child view.

the child view has many elements and I have given proptional heights to the elements and I have set some vertical spacings and alll.

in smaller iOS screen devices .. the child view size becomes large and I can see the element of child view outside of it ..

I want scroll view to have scroll and I should be able to see the spiled over item only If I scroll up

What am i doing wrong ...

Kindly help,

Dany